# android:permission on <intent-filter> or <action>

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, intentfilter, android-permissions

I got an app that defines 2 custom permissions:

- com.example.p1
- com.example.p2

Suppose there are 2 kind of external apps:

- one can send the Intent com.example.CREATE
- the other can send the Intent com.example.INSERT

I want to check in my app if the external app sending com.example.CREATE Intent has permission com.example.p1, and if the one sending com.example.INSERT has the permission com.example.p2.

One external app can have only one permission, not both.

I tried creating 2 intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.example.CREATE"  /> 
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.example.INSERT"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

but i don't know how to check the first permission in the 1st intent-filter and the second permission in the 2nd intent filter.

I hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `<activity-alias>` and put one of the `<intent-filter>` elements on it. Then, use `android:permission` on the `<activity>` (for its filter) and on the `<activity-alias>` (for its filter).